# Add blur image background to a xib programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, view, background, uiimageview

I have recently started dealing with my interface programatically and I want to set an image as background of my storyboard and then make it blur . 
I've seen sample codes like the following :

```
 UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Wormhole.jpg"]];
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
```

but as I said I am quit new to this . Can some one please explain how it works ? and where should I use it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest, just add an visual effect like this:

```
 UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Wormhole.jpg"]];
 [self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
 UIVisualEffectView *effect = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight]];
 [backgroundView addSubview:effect];
```

But this may cause performance problem. So the best solution should be that you redraw the image with blur , and set the blurred image as backgroundView's image .
How to blur an image, see [below](https://github.com/evanwdavis/Fun-with-Masks/blob/master/Fun%20with%20Masks/EWDBlurExampleVC.m):

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0]; 

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Wormhole.jpg"];
//create blurred image
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
//setting up Gaussian Blur (we could use one of many filters offered by Core Image)
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

//add our blurred image
backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

The Swift Code:

```
let backgroundView = UIImageView()
self.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
let image = UIImage(named: "Wormhole.jpg")
let context = CIContext(options: nil)
let inputImage = CIImage(CGImage: image!.CGImage!)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
filter!.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter!.setValue(15, forKey: "inputRadius")
let result = filter!.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage
let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result!, fromRect: inputImage.extent)
backgroundView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
```

Be care of the optional value.

Comment: this is objective-c right ? how can I do the same thing via Swift ? :)

Comment: Swift has the same API. Just translate it.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.1 version (added as an extension to UIImage):

```
extension UIImage {

    func blurred(withRadius radius: Int) -> UIImage {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let inputImage = CIImage(cgImage: self.cgImage!)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
        filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(radius, forKey: "inputRadius")
        let result = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: inputImage.extent)!
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }

}
```